# Select the items from a table that have different count() compared to other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables for exemple:

```
Table A:
  userid
-----------
 A
 B
 C
 D
 D

Table B:
  userid
-----------
 A
 B
 C
 D
 D
 D
 E
```

I need to get the items from Table B that their count() on Table B differs from their count() on Table A. From the exemple above, I need it to print:

```
Table Result:
-----------
D
E
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you need to get the counts for a table. Something like:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) as count
FROM a
GROUP BY userid;
```

Getting the counts from 'b' will be very similar.

If you had both of those query results as tables, then to get your result, you'd need to do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT aa.userid
FROM aa, bb
WHERE
  aa.userid = bb.userid AND 
  aa.count != bb.count;
```

Fortunately, you can combine everything like that:

```
WITH aa AS (
  SELECT userid, COUNT(*) as count
  FROM a
  GROUP BY userid),
bb AS (
  SELECT userid, COUNT(*) as count
  FROM b
  GROUP BY userid)
SELECT DISTINCT aa.userid
FROM aa, bb
WHERE
  aa.userid = bb.userid AND 
  aa.count != bb.count;
```

That's missing 'E', though, in the output. So we need to do a different join, and select a different thing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(aa.userid, bb.userid)
FROM aa
  FULL OUTER JOIN bb
  ON aa.userid = bb.userid
WHERE
  (aa.count != bb.count
   OR aa.count IS NULL
   OR bb.count IS NULL);
```

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` is to make sure we get results where there are rows in one table, but not the other. That adds rows with `NULL` values, which we need to consider. `COALESCE` grabs the first non-`NULL` value (so if table b has 'X', and table a doesn't, it will grab 'X').

Finally, there might be `NULL` in the count, too, so we handle that.

All together it looks like this:

```
WITH aa AS (
  SELECT userid, COUNT(*) as count
  FROM a
  GROUP BY userid),
bb AS (
  SELECT userid, COUNT(*) as count
  FROM b
  GROUP BY userid)
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(aa.userid, bb.userid)
FROM aa
  FULL OUTER JOIN bb
  ON aa.userid = bb.userid
WHERE
  (aa.count != bb.count
   OR aa.count IS NULL
   OR bb.count IS NULL);
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/12e28/7)

**Edited to add:** There are definitely more compact ways to do this (as is evidenced by the other answers). This way has the benefit of building up from simple queries, which is why I like it.

Comment: Wow huge one.. Great

Comment: It's incorrect. Task conditions are: "I need to get the items from Table B". Your query returns items from TableA as well, which are missing in TableB.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT B.userid
FROM (SELECT userid, count(*) AS countB FROM TableB GROUP BY userid) B
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid, count(*) AS countA FROM TableA GROUP BY userid) A USING(userid)
WHERE A.countA != B.countB OR A.countA IS NULL;
```

Edited to add sandbox for testing: https://rextester.com/CTKD25341

Answer (score 0):

I also made one myself:

```
select distinct userid from table_b where 
(select count(userid) from table_b where userid = a.userid) != 
(select count(userid) from table_a where userid = a.userid);
```